# Can't email chats on whatapp

Tags: email, whatsapp-messenger

So I have a nexus 6P and so does my husband.  His email feature for emailing WhatsApp messages works fine but mine does not.  Every time I try to send my chat through email on my phone it does not actually attach the chat.  It will still go through the process of sending it as an email like it normally would however it won't actually attach a file.  On my husbands it will attach a txt file when the email is sent.  On mine, it will send the email but without any attachments.

Please help.  I've tried countless times and with numerous different contacts.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions given to the app on both phones? Are you using the same email app? Have you made sure that both phones run the same app + Android version, fully updated?

Comment: Not sure why WhatsApp is not attaching a .txt file as it is doing in my phone when I tried. Try one more thing: when sending an email, choose "Attach Media" option (although you may not actually want to send media but only for testing purpose) and see if it can attach media files (.jpg in case of images etc.). This should probably force WhatsApp to attach email chat as .txt file (just a guess, not sure)